# set csv encoding when downloading a file

Tags: javascript, csv, encoding, papaparse

I am using react, [Paparse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs) and [encoding-japanese](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding-japanese)

With Paparse I can upload a CSV and decode it from Shift-JS. but the opposite operation is not supported by the library.

I added the encoding-japanese, in order to convert a string to SHIFT-js and download it.

Here is my code :

```
    const csv = csvParser.unparse({
        "fields": ["行形式","取引番号","取引日","支払期限","顧客番号","顧客企業名","顧客電話番号","送付先郵便番号","請求書発行日","郵送","メール送付","取引金額","明細","単価","数量","金額","消費税率","税込対象額_10%","税込対象額_8%","税込対象額_経8%","税込対象額_旧8%","税込対象額_非","税込対象額_対象外"],
        "data": [
            ["取引","transaction-20200218-094750_1","2020/02/18","2020/03/31","DP79","Sample1Corp","03-0000-0000","123-4567","2020/02/19","0","1","110","","","","","","110","","","",""]
        ]
    });
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    const sjisArray = Encoding.convert(csv, 'SJIS', 'UTF8');
    console.log(sjisArray)
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['\ufeff'+sjisArray], {type: "text/csv;charset=shift-js"}));
    a.download = "取引サンプル.csv";
    a.click();
```

It throw no error, but my csv file when I open it in notepad, it is still in UTF8 with BOM.

I wish to have it in shift-js.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

Your `Encoding` library is currently returning a DOMString, because you passed such a DOMString as input.
This means that your `Blob` constructor will convert this DOMString to UTF-8 and that's what you'll have in your file: an UTF-8 version of the UTF-16 representation of the Shift-JIS encoded text.

Least to say, that's not what you want.

Quick looking at that library's docs, it seems that the best would be to pass an ArrayBuffer version of your text to encode, so that it returns to you an Array of the bytes values (like an Uint8Array, except they use a normal Array for whatever reasons...).

Then from that Array of bytes, you'll be able to generate a new ArrayBuffer that you will be able to pass to your Blob without it converting it back to UTF-8.

```js
const csv = Papa.unparse({
    "fields": ["行形式","取引番号","取引日","支払期限","顧客番号","顧客企業名","顧客電話番号","送付先郵便番号","請求書発行日","郵送","メール送付","取引金額","明細","単価","数量","金額","消費税率","税込対象額_10%","税込対象額_8%","税込対象額_経8%","税込対象額_旧8%","税込対象額_非","税込対象額_対象外"],
    "data": [
        ["取引","transaction-20200218-094750_1","2020/02/18","2020/03/31","DP79","Sample1Corp","03-0000-0000","123-4567","2020/02/19","0","1","110","","","","","","110","","","",""]
    ]
});
// First convert our DOMString to an ArrayBuffer
const utf8Array = new TextEncoder().encode( csv );
// pass it to Encoding so we get back an Array of bytes
const sjisArray = Encoding.convert(utf8Array, 'SJIS', 'UTF8');
// now we can make our Blob without auto encoding
const blob = new Blob( [ new Uint8Array( sjisArray ) ] );

const a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'Shift-JIS.csv';
a.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
a.textContent = 'download';
document.body.append( a );
// just to check we encoded it correctly
readAsText( blob, 'Shift-JIS' )
  .then( txt => console.log( 'read back as Shift-JIS:', txt ) );
readAsText( blob, 'utf-8' )
  .then( txt => console.log( 'read back as UTF-8:', txt ) );
  
function readAsText( blob, encoding ) {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = rej;
    reader.onload = (evt) => res( reader.result );
    reader.readAsText( blob, encoding );
  } );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/encoding-japanese/1.0.30/encoding.min.js"></script>
```